# Troubles adding new languages with Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm new to Symfony trying to add another language version to site.
I was trying to add language version in .htaccess and locales.
I've added this strings to routing.yml:

```
contacts:
  param: { module: homepage, action: contacts }
  prefix_path:    /:sf_culture/contacts
```

But everytime I got 404 when I go to the /en/contacts.
I need to move english version to the /en and another language keep on /
What am I doing wrong and how can I add language version to the site correctly?